# CRM2011 FetchXml Error - System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse

Tags: soap, dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

I have change server and now i'm having a problem with fechxml, all other SOAP services are working 100%, like updade, create, delete, expect fetch, and i don`t have idea or the reason for this to be happening.

Mesagem error:

```
@"Server was unable to process request.
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
       at ws.CrmService.CrmService.Fetch(String fetchXml) in c:\CRMServer\ws\ws\Web References\CrmService\Reference.cs:line 180
       at wsService.Crm2013test(String nomechave) in c:\CRMServer\ws\ws\test\test2013.cs:line 416"
```

Reference.cs file:

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("CorrelationTokenValue")]
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("CrmAuthenticationTokenValue")]
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("CallerOriginTokenValue")]         [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/Fetch",
 RequestNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices",
 ResponseNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices",
 Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal,
 ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
public string Fetch(string fetchXml) {
    object[] results = this.Invoke("Fetch", new object[] {fetchXml});
    return ((string)(results[0]));
}
```

test2013 file:

```
 public PrxActivityResult Crm2013test(string nomechave)

{
    PrxActivityResult res = new PrxActivityResult();
    Tb_Log_Create("WS.Crm2013test", "Entrada", "Codigo; valor:" + nomechave, "Anónimo");


    try
    {

        OrganizationServiceProxy organizationProxy = CrmServiceManager.GetOrganisationServiceProxy();
        CrmService service = CrmServiceManager.GetCrmService();

        Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ConditionExpression condition = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ConditionExpression("name", Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ConditionOperator.Like, new string[] { nomechave });

        Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.FilterExpression filter = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.FilterExpression();
        filter.AddCondition(condition);
        filter.FilterOperator = Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.LogicalOperator.And;

        Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.QueryExpression query = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.QueryExpression();
        query.EntityName = "account";
        query.ColumnSet = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ColumnSet(true);
       // query.Criteria = filter;

        EntityCollection ec = organizationProxy.RetrieveMultiple(query);

        string fetchXml = @"<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
            <entity name='account'>
            <attribute name='name'/>
            <attribute name='telephone1'/>
            </entity></fetch>";

        string ret = service.Fetch(fetchXml);
        res.XmlContent = ret;

        }


    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return res;
}
```

Any one have an idea of what is? Thanks a million

Comment: can you please explain what are you trying to do by writing `result.XmlContent = return;`  I don't think you can even build this code by using a reserved keyword as variable name.

Comment: Hi Scorpion, the issue is not there, `result.XmlContent = return` ist ok, the problem is whend execute the `service.Fetch(fetchXml)` give me the Exception. The `result.XmlContent = return` it will return me the xml content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if there is something else, but you're missing your closing `</Entity>` Tag in your fetch XML.

### Edit

wondering why you're rolling you're own Fetch SOAP.

Should just be doing something like this:

```
string fetchXml = @"<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
    <entity name='account'>
    <attribute name='name'/>
    <attribute name='telephone1'/>
</fetch>";

EntityCollection ec = organizationProxy.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchXml));
```

Also, `OrganizationServiceProxy` implements `IDisposible` and therefor should be wrapped in a using statement

Comment: Hi Daryl, yes it's missing, but i failed on the copy & paste, but even with the `</Entity>` does not work!

Comment: @HugoSilva Fix your post then, and see updated answer.  And `string return = service.Fetch(fetchXml);` doesn't compile for me.

Comment: It Works OK, i can get the info but now who can i put the result on a string? Example: <name>abs</name><telephone1>1232</telephone1> ? This was what i have in the past and it works, i really dont know why is not working enymore.

Comment: @HugoSilva You could always serialize the entities back, or gen your own XML based on the attributes collection.  Or ask a new Question, "How do I access the result of FetchXML as XML rather than entities?"